# Creating an encrypted password

Tags: sql, python-3.x, oracle, oauth-2.0

I have a Python job that connects to Oracle database to extract data from multiple tables, generate both a flat file and export to another database. This job is intended to be scheduled in a server for nightly runs.

Currently, I have a configuration file that contains username, password, host, service_name, dbname, etc…

Would it be possible to create an encrypted string that can be used in place of password, which is specifically meant for this job and set of tables.

My investigations led me to `maskpass()`, `cryptography()`, etc... However, I still end up specifying that password somewhere.

I also discovered OAuth 2.0 but not sure if I can stand up that service, link that to Oracle database to generate an access token that can be used in place of a password.

Comment: you can use argon2 https://pypi.org/project/argon2-cffi/

Comment: Oracle provides options for passwordless connection. Would one of these help? https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/109170/103604

Answer (score 0):

To prevent storing password on the server, do this:

1. Write a script that takes the plain text password and generates the encrypted password. You store this script and the associated key and salt in a secure place (like a password protected git repo), not on the server.
2. You specify the encrypted password generated above in the decrypt function and then connect to the database.

You can use any of the Python encryption libraries like cryptography or rsa to encrypt and decrypt the password.